# Get MethodInfo for ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, linq, system.reflection

I've got collection `ICollection<T>` and I need to find method "Where". How could I do that?

I tried something like this:

```
System.Type type = typeof(ICollection<T>);
MethodInfo info = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetMethod("Where");
```

but it doesn't work. I need it to create dynamic expression

Answer (score 3):

It's an extension method, therefore it's not on the interface itself but on the `Enumerable` class:

```
typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods("Where", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
```

Then choose the overload you need.

Comment: Nice, how could I avoid ambigous fit to function in case there is lot of Where(...) definitions?

Comment: You can either use `Where` to filter out the results of `GetMethods`, or more seriously you can use the `GetMethod` overload which takes an array of parameter types as argument to disambiguate the overloads. Pass in all the parameter types of the overload you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
typeof(ICollection<>);
```

to get the type of `ICollection<T>`.But, the `Where` method isn't defined in `ICollection<T>`.You should get the method from static `Enumerable` class.